# Can Non indexing fields be used in filter?

Tags: database, optimization, teradata

In teradata source I have filter to restrict unnecessary reading of data ,since it contains more than 1 billion records,for optimization purpose.Now the filter condition contains only indexing fields. My question is can I use non indexing fields in filter? If yes please provide some material proving the same.

Comment: When you talk about "filter", do you mean join conditions?

Answer (score 1):

If by "filter" you are refering to a WHERE clause or an ON condition, then yes, you can refer to a non-indexed column.  For best performance, you might want to "collect statistics" on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but if it's non indexed then performance will be poor. For more on collecting stats in Teradata 13.10 refer to the link http://developer.teradata.com/blog/carrie/2012/04/teradata-13-10-statistics-collection-recommendations